# Calculate displacement through a force acting on body during some time

Tags: forces, kinematics, distance

By definition 1 Newton is the force that acting on 1 kg body during 1 second will move it on 1 meter. It is clear.

I confused on calculating the distance, with another force and mass. Obviously, 2 Newtons on 1kg body during 1 second will move body on 2 meters, right? Then 2 N on 2 kg during 1 second will move on 4 meters?

Which formula should I use?

$s = ut + \dfrac{1}{2}  at^2$ - this one will give o.5 meters for 1N 1kg body during 1 second

$$s = 0 + \dfrac{1}{2}  \dfrac{F}{m}t^2 = \dfrac{1}{2}\times\dfrac{\frac{kg*m}{s^2}}{kg}\times s^2$$
$$s = \frac{1}{2}\dfrac{kg*m*s^2}{kg*s^2}$$
$$s = \frac{1}{2}m=0.5\space meters$$

Is this formula correct?

---

Anywhere in internet I see exactly the first formula with $\frac{1}{2}$, but it is senseless. Even if to operate not with force and mass but with acceleration it makes no sense, because acceleration **ONE meter** per **ONE second** during **ONE second** gives **HALF meter** displacement.

Where is the logic? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the first sentence is incorrect, leading to problems using formulas from kinematics (which is the study of motion without its cause).

The Newton is the force needed to accelerate $1$ kilogram at $1$ meter/second squared. To put it another way, when the mass is constant, Newton's second law is $F=m a$. So, with mass in $kg$ and acceleration in $m/s^2$ the force is in $kg \ m/s^2$ which basically everyone agrees to call $N$ for Newton.

From definitions of velocity and acceleration in a straight line with constant acceleration, distance traveled from rest is $S=at^2/2$ so applying $1\  N$ on $1 \ kg$, the $a=1m/s^2$ and $S=.5 m$.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, seems that the formula is indeed correct